# What is the purpose of : in scanf?

Tags: c

```
scanf("%d:%d:%d%s", &hh, &mm, &ss, t12)
```

When taking multiple inputs for the time to be displayed the input is written as above where : is used in input statements the above line works fine but can someone explain the need and uses of colon in the input statement

Comment: It means a literal `:` between the numbers. Could you please break your question into sentences?

Comment: You would benefit from reading [scanf(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Answer (score 1):

From the standard, `C11 7.21.6.2 The fscanf function /3 and /6`:

> The format is composed of zero or more directives: one or more white-space 
>   characters, an ordinary multibyte character (neither `%` nor a white-space character), or a conversion specification.
>
> A directive that is an ordinary multibyte character is executed by reading the next characters of the stream. If any of those characters differ from the ones composing the directive, the directive fails and the differing and subsequent characters remain unread.

Hence the `:` simply means "make sure that the next character in the stream is a colon". Nothing more, nothing less.

Your format *string* simply means you'll be able to scan things like `12:34:56am` - without the literal colons in the format string, the scan would fail.